# как задать стиль для внешнего псевдотега

Tags: css, css3, html5

есть код

```
<div class="switcher">

<label data-bx-user-consent="<?=htmlspecialcharsbx($config)?>" class="main-user-consent-request">
    <input type="checkbox" value="Y" <?=($arParams['IS_CHECKED'] ? 'checked' : '')?> name="<?=htmlspecialcharsbx($arParams['INPUT_NAME'])?>">
    <span class="main-user-consent-request-announce"><?=htmlspecialcharsbx($arResult['INPUT_LABEL'])?></span>
</label>
</div>
```

как написать css для `label::after` при условие что `input - checked`?

вот примерно что я хочу , но это не работает

```
    .switcher label::after + input[type=checkbox]:checked
    {
        left: 2.5rem; 
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для псевдоэлемента так не получится. Создайте элемент.

```css
label{
  display:inline-block;
}
.aws{
  content:'';
  display:inline-block;
  width:1em;
  height:1em;
  border:1px solid;
}
input:checked ~ .aws{
  background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" />
  <span>ololo</span>
  <span class="aws"></span>
</label>
```